# biggest/lowest |y|/|x| value for a certain linear mapping

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, optimization, linear-transformations, maxima-minima

## Introduction:

suppose you have a linear mapping from an euclidean vector space V to an euclidean vector space w.

This mapping can be represented using a matrix A.

for all x out of v that are not zero, you can evaluate |Ax|/|x|.

because of linearity, if two nonzero vectors x and x' out of v are collinear, |Ax|/|x|=|Ax'|/|x'|.

```
x'=kx (collinear vectors)

therefore:

|Ax'|/|x'|=|A(kx)|/|kx|=|k(Ax)|/|kx|=k|(Ax)|/(k|x|)=|Ax|/|x|
```

**but this implies that the image set of f : v -> R, with f(x)=|Ax|/|x| is the same as the image set of g : {x out of v| |x|=1} -> R, with g(x)=f(x)=|Ax|/|x|
especially, this image set is a closed intervall on R, reaching from some lower bound a to some higher bound b.** (Proof?)

## So here is the question:

**How to calculate those bounds (a and b) given the matrix representation A of some linear mapping?**

or more precisely:

given two euclidean Vector spaces v and w,

and a matrix A, representing a linear mapping from v to w,

there exists a function l : v/{0} -> R,

given by l(x)=|Ax|/|x|.

the image set of l is an intervall [a,b]

how to calculate a and b given the matrix A?

## why I am asking this:

> Doing 3D graphics, I want to implement some [specular lighting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specular_highlight).
>
> In my approach, I have a surface wich is projected onto another.
>
> when approximating it, one may model this projection as consisting of
>   two compounds, a "squeezing", attributed to the angle between the
>   surfaces, and an "uniform scale", wich is attributed to the distance
>   between the surfaces.
>
> I can barely get the hands on the projection matrix A (a 2x2 matrix,
>   invertibe most of the times), and now i am struggling to decompose it
>   into these two compounds.
>
> calculating these bounds, i could evaluate the "uniform scale" part,
>   and removing that part, i could get my hands on the other...
>
> however, since the matrix is different for every fragment, (fragment
>   is something like a "pixel", a smallest unit) I need a very efficient
>   formula taking the entries of the 2x2 matrix describing the projection
>   and calculating the upper bound of the "image set interval" associated
>   with this matrix (as described above).

Comment: Your question is really hard to read. Look at the $\min,\max$ singular values.

Comment: i know there have to be such min, max singular values, corresponding to x values out of two 1D sub vector spaces in the case of v being a two dimensional vectorspace (ignoring special cases here). but how do i find them?

Comment: Compute the $\min,\max$ singular values. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition

Comment: Thanks, this solves the issue. I didn't know about that technique.

Comment: Glad to help. I think the SVD should be taught very early on.